# VSTS - cannot deploy to an on premise web server

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am new to VSTS build and deploy and I am struggling with it.
I have a solution that contains a Web Core API and a ASP.Net web project.
I have done my build and now I want to deploy the build to an on premise web server.
When I look at my artifacts, everything looks OK;
[image]

So when I set up a deploy definition I start with an empty environment and I add a task. It looks to me that given I want to move the artifacts to an on premise web server I should be using the Windows Machine File Copy task. But when I do I find that I do not have access to the drop folder. How do I fix this (and have I selected the correct task?).
[image]

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or an on-prem agent?

Comment: I am using hosted agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the hosted agent. The hosted agent can't deploy to an on-prem server -- it has no network route.

You can either use [Deployment Groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/deployment-groups/) (the agent is installed on your target machine and talks directly to VSTS), or you can install your own on-prem build/release server, then push the bits to the target machine using the Windows Machine File Copy task.

Comment: I created a deployment group, but I can't work out how to set up the agents on the target machine.

Comment: @arame3333 1. Click deployment group you created >Details
2. Select System in Type of machines to register (e.g. windows)
3. Copy registration PowerShell script 
4. Log on a machine (used as agent)
5. Run Windows PowerShell as administrator
6. Paste the copied script >press Enter

Comment: I have a proxy server error ("The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.") when I run the script on the server machine. I presume this means the only way round this is to request a change in the firewall settings? I need to explain this to my sceptical colleagues.

Comment: @arame3333 What's the result if you setup a on private build agent directly? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows

Comment: Deployment groups is the correct answer and gets my tick. I have a new problem and I will ask a new question.